# Invalid number error - NVL function

Tags: oracle, nvl

I just found out an error (**Invalid Number**) in this line of SQL code:

```
WHERE NVL((submit_time - req_time) * 24 ,12121)  != 12121
```

Can someone explain what may be the problem?

Comment: what is the possible values in submit_time and req_time

Comment: i think you are either trying (null - req_time) or (submit_time - null)?

Comment: Sometimes submit_time - req_time returns Null values . im trying to replace the null values with 12121

Comment: @SathishK - Returning null wont cause problem here. can u let us know what is the data type of those fields.

Comment: Both are datetime data types

Comment: Oracle doesnt have datetime data type. Is it date or timestamp?

Comment: Yes.its timestamp :)

Comment: Subtracting timestamps  gives INTERVAL type. So you shouldnt be comparing it with numbers.

Comment: My Aim is result should not contain any Null values . that's why im doing this ..can you help ?

Answer (score 1):

Can you try something like this , to make sure that we are not dealing with null on those two fields

```
where decode(submit_time,NULL,12121,decode(req_time,null,12121,(submit_time - req_time) * 24))
```

Comment: +1 . Good one . Little modification met my expectation